# Is it necessary to add 'to' before 'develop projects'?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context, formality

> Furthermore, this master is crucial for enhancing his capacity to research and **develop** projects related to subterranean water, which are required to supply the urgent demand of water for zones with scarcity.

Is it necessary to add ***to*** before **develop projects**?

Comment: As said by Stephen in his answer, both ways are correct. It is more of a formality to use the proposition. But I would personally recommend not using it here, since the sentence sounds more complete without it. And of course, it is not a necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“to research and develop” is better if you think of them as a single activity.

“to research and to develop” is better if you think of them as two separate activities.

Both are valid ways of thinking and speaking.